# Auto Responder - Existing Header

Tags: fiddler

Using Fiddler's auto responder, is there a way to take the header, decompress it, replace certain characters, then re-compress it?

For example, say I have a header that includes a hash when viewed in TextView, however I would like to manipulate something else say for example, some text named "Hello World", and change it to "Foo".  Its originally compressed with g-zip, however in order to edit it, Fiddler would have to decompress it, make the changes, then re-compress it.

Is there a way to do with with auto responder?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use the script engine for this. http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/browse_thread/thread/5efc5d74c116f42b